# excel macro create pivot tables with column label

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table and recorded in macro. I was able to display my desired output when doing it manually but when I ran my macro, the pivot table shows differently.

Here is my expected output.

```
Count of Date Occurred  Column Labels                               
Row Labels  17.07.2017  18.07.2017  19.07.2017  20.07.2017  21.07.2017  22.07.2017  23.07.2017  24.07.2017  Grand Total
100117975           1                       1
100117976               1                   1
100117977       1                           1
100117979                       1           1
100117982   1                               1
100117988               1                   1
100117991   2   2   2       1           1   8
```

Below is the recorded code in macro.

```
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "DataDump!R1C1:R373C4", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="DataResult!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTableResult", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("DataResult").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableResult").PivotFields("Date Occurred")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableResult").PivotFields("ID")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableResult").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTableResult").PivotFields("Date Occurred"), "Count of Date Occurred", xlCount
```

and below is the output from macro.

```
Row Labels  Count of Date Occurred
100117975   1
100117976   1
100117977   1
100117979   1
100117982   1
100117988   1
100117991   8
100117992   2
100117993   7
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I tried doing this but got the Run-time error 450. 
`ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableResult").AddDataField
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableResult").PivotFields("ID")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTableResult").PivotFields ("Date Occurred"), "Count of Date Occurred", xlCount`

Comment: same result when I moved it.

Comment: I copied the first WIth/End block after the add data and it worked. The first block should still be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the first WIth/End block after the add data and it worked. The first block should still be there